# Spring session, recover from "local class incompatible" after deployments

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

Spring session stores serialized objects in my database. The problem is, sometimes my code changes. Sometimes my objects change. This is normal. However, I get errors like this:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [byte[]] to type [java.lang.Object] for value '{-84, ..., 112}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mysite.MyClass; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1432849980928799324, local class serialVersionUID = 8454085305026634675
```

I get this error by invoking a Spring Boot endpoint with HttpSession as an argument, such as this one:

```
@GetMapping("/stuff")
public @ResponseBody MyClass getStuff(HttpSession session) {
    try {
        Object myObject = session.getAttribute("MyClass");
        if (myObject != null && myObject instanceof MyClass) {
            return (MyClass) myObject;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Invalid session data", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, because the exception is thrown **before** the method gets invoked, I am not able to recover from this normal, expected error.

As a workaround, I am forced to delete the entire session table each deployment, even though most of the objects are still compatible!

To be clear, the solution is NOT to add a serialVersionUuid. Because the objects really do change in non-compatible ways from one deployment to the next. This is not a serialization question. This is a Spring Session error recovery question.

My question is: How can I gracefully recover from these issues?

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide details but I assume you are using Spring's JDBC session implementation enabled by `@EnableJdbcHttpSession`?

In this case you can take a look at `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration` and particularly at `setSpringSessionConversionService` and `setConversionService`. I believe if you provide your own implementation (you can see example at `createConversionServiceWithBeanClassLoader`) then you should be able to catch deserialization error and return empty session.

I think all you need is derive `MyNotFailingSessionDeserializer` from `DeserializingConverter`, override `convert` method, catch `SerializationFailedException` and return null or empty session (not sure if either works).

Then you create your conversion service like `createConversionServiceWithBeanClassLoader` does but use your `MyNotFailingSessionDeserializer` instead of `DeserializingConverter`